# SOCP: Recovering primal from dual

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming

Consider the following second-order cone program (SOCP):
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\min_x & c^\top x\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & \|A_ix+b_i\|_2 \leq c_i^\top x+d_i \ \forall i
\end{array}
$$

Suppose I solve the dual of a second-order cone program (SOCP) for the dual variables $\lambda_i,u_i$:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\max_{\lambda,u} & -(\lambda^\top d + \sum_i u_i^\top b_i)\\
\mathrm{s.t.} & \sum_i A_i^\top u_i -\lambda_i c_i = 0\ \forall i\\
&\|u_i\|_2\leq\lambda_i \ \forall i
\end{array}
$$

**Is there a standard technique for recovering the primal variable $x$ from $(\lambda,u)$, assuming the SOCP exhibits strong duality?**

---

**Note:**  I am using the notation of [this document](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture10.pdf).

When I attempt to plug $\lambda$ back into the Lagrange multiplier expression, everything seems to just cancel out!  I managed to solve the dual of my SOCP using an elegant optimization technique but am struggling to translate to the original primal problem.

Comment: Justin, would you mind making your question self-contained? Just in case the page you linked to gets removed at some point in the future...

Comment: No problem, will do so after a few meetings today...

Comment: Note that if you solve the SOCP as a linear conic program, then $u_1,\ldots,u_m$ are also dual variables. Do you have access to these too?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the $u$'s and the $\lambda$'s.

Comment: OK, edited to make the question self-contained.  But now I'm hoping you guys can help me solve it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard technique is to solve the optimality conditions as a
linear system of equations. Let us rewrite your problem into standard
form
$$
\begin{align*}
\text{maximize } & -c^{T}x\text{ s.t. }\begin{bmatrix}-c_{i}^{T}\\
-A_{i}
\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}t_{i}\\
z_{i}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}d_{i}\\
b_{i}
\end{bmatrix},\;\begin{bmatrix}t_{i}\\
z_{i}
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathrm{SOC},\\
\text{minimize } & \sum_{i=1}^{m}\begin{bmatrix}d_{i}\\
b_{i}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{i}\\
u_{i}
\end{bmatrix}\text{ s.t. }\sum_{i=1}^{m}\begin{bmatrix}-c_{i}^{T}\\
-A_{i}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{i}\\
u_{i}
\end{bmatrix}=-c,\;\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{i}\\
u_{i}
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathrm{SOC}.
\end{align*}
$$
The classical optimality conditions are written
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\begin{bmatrix}-c_{i}^{T}\\
-A_{i}
\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{i}\\
u_{i}
\end{bmatrix} & =-c,\\
\begin{bmatrix}-c_{i}^{T}\\
-A_{i}
\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}t_{i}\\
z_{i}
\end{bmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}b_{i}\\
d_{i}
\end{bmatrix}\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\},\\
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{i} & u_{i}^{T}\\
u_{i} & \lambda_{i}I
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}t_{i}\\
z_{i}
\end{bmatrix} & =0\qquad\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\},
\end{align*}
$$
see Theorem 16, Alizadeh & Goldfarb, **Second-order cone programming**,
*Math. Program.*, 2001. Notice that the system of equations
is *linear* over $x,t_{i},z_{i}$ with $\lambda_{i},u_{i}$ fixed. Substituting
$\lambda_{i}\gets\lambda_{i}^{\star}$ and $u_{i}\gets u_{i}^{\star}$
and solving the linear equations 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{i} & u_{i}^{T}\\
u_{i} & \lambda_{i}I
\end{bmatrix}\left(\begin{bmatrix}c_{i}^{T}\\
A_{i}
\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}b_{i}\\
d_{i}
\end{bmatrix}\right)=0 \qquad \forall i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}
$$
yields the primal-optimal solution $x^{\star},t_{i}^{\star},z_{i}^{\star}$, assuming that the equations are full-rank or overdetermined (given strong duality, a zero-residual solution must exist). If the equations are underdetermined, then we would have to reimpose the constraint $[t_i^\star, z_i^\star]\in \mathrm{SOC}$ and solve a SOCP feasibility problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  To make sure I understand properly, what is SOC here?  It looks like your notation differs a bit from the Alizadeh/Goldfarb paper (sorry, I'm new to this area!).

Comment: SOC = second order cone. My notation was adopted to match the ones in the prompt.

Comment: Yes, I guessed this much :-) .  So, (t; z) in SOC means $||z||\leq t$?

If so, could their be a typo in the first line of math?  It looks like $t_i=-c_i^\top x - d_i$ -- maybe there should be a minus rather than a plus before the $(t_i,z_i)$?

Comment: Fixed. Actually, the dual problem in the prompt has a sign error. Also thought about it a little more and realized that the optimality conditions may not be enough. I'd have to think about it more.

Comment: Thanks! Can you correct the sign error on the prompt as well?

Comment: Done. Yeah, I wrote this answer noting that SOCP strong duality implies $u^Tz + \lambda t = 0$ but also $tu + \lambda z = 0.$ This is similar to LP strong duality $x^Tz=0$ also implying the elementwise equality $x\circ z = 0$. Sadly, this does not always produce enough constraints to immediately reconstruct the primal solution.

Comment: Got it!  Now I have to puzzle through how it applies to my particular problem ... I've been totally stumped!